# Can you make something px and % in same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Hello i am trying to make text box that has 480 px but also works like % so when i shrink my page it also shrinks and does not stay same size every time.
If i use 100% when i put big file it makes my text box really big.
If i use 480px box cant be scalable.

```
.input-group-attach {
width: 480px;
position: relative;
display: inline-flex;
}
```

Simple Div from my code can i make it like:

```
.input-group-attach {
width: 480px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
display: inline-flex;
}
```

Or something like this?

Comment: `max-width: 480px;
width: 100%;` ?

Comment: yes that is it, thank you so much.